# Move files from specifically named folders / move files up one level

Tags: bash, find, mv

The goals is to move files out of the lowest level folder, back up one directory.

This does a great job but moves files higher up the folder hierarchy as well.

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -execdir mv '{}' ../ \;
```

So if these jpgs were sat in a folder called 'photos', I want to move them up one level eg)

> **../**

I've tried changing the '*.jpg' parameter to include the folder and tried using the folder instead of the dot after file. Also tried -maxdepth and -mindepth but they had no effect.

**EDIT: This is for multiple folders i.e. it needs to recurse through an entire drive.**

Comment: If all `.jpg`'s are in the same folder you can use `mv -t ../ *.jpg` ....if they on different folders then your command will move each of them to their respective parent directories.do you want to move them to the same directory?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you need that `cd photos; mv *jpg ../` or `mv /path/to/photos/*jpg /path/to` won't do? Do you have multiple directories?

Comment: So, you want to traverse whole directory tree and move each file to its respective parent directory? Is that precise ?

Comment: Just jpgs contained in folders called 'photos'. Any other jpgs should not be moved.

Comment: Do you have more than one folder named `photos`?

Comment: @heemayl Yes, several. Otherwise I would go into each one and copy paste the files out.

Comment: Check my answer then..

Comment: Can I not just put a rule in to say if current folder doesn't contain directories, move files?

Comment: That is what the first version of my answer does.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I'm not that familiar with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Move files from the lowest sub directory up one level

The script below searches a directory for *the lowest* sub directory (= without sub directories) recursively and moves all found files in the folder(s) up one level, as literally asked for in *The goals is to move files out of the lowest level folder, back up one directory*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import shutil
import os
import sys

directory = sys.argv[1] 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for dr in dirs:
        dr = root+"/"+dr
        # find folders without subfolders (= lowest level)
        if len(next(os.walk(dr))[1]) == 0:
            # direct superior directory
            up = dr[:dr.rfind("/")]
            # move files from lowest level one level up
            for f in os.listdir(dr):
                shutil.move(dr+"/"+f, up+"/"+f)
```

#### To use:

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `reorganize.py`
2. Run it by the command:

   ```
   python /path/to/reorganize.py <directory_to_reorganize>
   ```

   If the name of your directory (to reorganize) contains spaces, use quotes:

   ```
   python /path/to/reorganize.py '<directory_to_reorganize>'
   ```

---

### EDIT

As mentioned in a comment, with a little change, the script can be used to only move files from a folder *name* up one level. The moste efficient way is to do that directly after

```
for dr in dirs:
```

Then the script would be:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import os
import sys

directory = sys.argv[1]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for dr in dirs:
        if dr == "<folder_name>":
            dr = root+"/"+dr
            # direct superior directory
            up = dr[:dr.rfind("/")]
            # move files from lowest level one level up
            for f in os.listdir(dr):
                shutil.move(dr+"/"+f, up+"/"+f)
```

Comment: I presume you can modify this to only look for specific folders, presumably another condition in the if len(next... statement.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle absolutely, what do you have in mind?

Comment: I get the error... /usr/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '/<my folder>'

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: My ubuntu version is 12.04. It said install python3 which I did.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle aarrggh, If I would have known you were using 12.04, I wouldn't have made you install python3. I'll make it fit for python2. Probably the separately installed python3 misses libraries or modules the "native" 14.04 version includes.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle see my updated answer, now for python 2, without using `pathlib`

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle Perfect! Glad it works.

Answer (score 1):

The following will move all `.jpg` files to their respective parent directories if the `.jpg` files are only under the directory named `photos` (there can be multiple directory named `photos`):

```
find . -type f -path '*/photos/*' -not -path '*/photos/*/*' -name '*.jpg' \
-execdir mv -i {} .. \;
```

`-path '*/photos/*'` will ensure that the path will contain `photos` but the files can only be under the the `photos` directory (`-not -path '*/photos/*/*'`).

Also note that, if the directories not to travel (not `photos`) are fixed and smaller in numbers or has specific patterns then you might be interested in `-prune` too.

Comment: I got the error `find: paths must precede expression:  -execdir` presumably because of the slash after jpg'. No files moved after removing this slash.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle You might have removed quotes..quotes are important..use exactly as i did..

Answer (score 1):

If all your target files are in directories named `photos`, you could do something like:

```
find . -type d -name photos -exec bash -c 'cd {} && mv *jpg ../' \;
```

That will look for directories names `photos`, then launch a bash shell that will `cd` into each of them and move all `.jpg` files to the parent directory.

Comment: Why is the directory name not in quotes? PS. Didn't work.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle no need for quotes, there's no wildcard and it's not a variable, just a simple string.  How did it fail? You need to run it from the parent directory of the photos dirs. It will work as long as all the target folders are named exactly `photos`

Comment: The command ran without errors, it just didn't move any files.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle could the directories be named `Photos` instead? Did you run it from the correct directory? Try running `find /home/terdon/foo/  -type d -name photos -exec bash -c "ls {}/*" \;`, does that return anything? If not, you are in the wrong place or the directories have different names. Feel free to ping me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room), I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Will find the lowest level in every directory branch and use it as a base for your find and move '*.jpg' up one level.

```
#!/bin/bash

treedir="."
mapfile -d '' < <(find "$treedir" -depth -type d -print0)

L=""
A=()
for D in "${MAPFILE[@]}"; do
    [[ $L != $D/* ]] && A+=("$D"); L="$D"
done

for basedir in "${A[@]}"; do
    find "$basedir" -name '*.jpg' -type f -execdir mv -i -t .. '{}' \;
done
```